# jQuery(window).height inaccurate

Tags: jquery

I'm doing a simple test on $(window).height() and I'm getting a value of 2602 on a screen resolution of 1366 x 768.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var W = $(window).width();
    var H = $(window).height();

    console.log('W ' + W);
    console.log('H ' + H);

}
```

Outputs:

> W 1226 
>   H 2602

Any tips on how to debug this or what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: Using chrome and FF

I'm literally typing this in console: jQuery(window).height();

Comment: Are you sure your actual window isn’t that tall or something?

Comment: The window is the browser viewport right? I'm zoomed at 100% so it should accurately reflect the pixels on the screen?

Comment: It was on the off chance that you were using a non-maximized window several times taller than your screen :) But yes, it should, shouldn’t it?

Comment: @AlxVallejo In which browser?

Comment: Works fine for me here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9qHPE/

Comment: What if you wrap it in a resize function to see changes? $(window).resize(function() { console.log...});

Comment: Are you sure your computer thinks it's sideways? :-)

Comment: @Phil-R Great idea, but the height is stuck at 2685. It will fluctuate when I resize again but it's still abnormally large.

Comment: @j08691 Is the jsfiddle example suppose to reflect the height of the JavaScript div? ie, .CodeMirror-gutter CodeMirror-linenumbers? Because that's what I'm getting a read on. If that div is 260px height then that's what I'm getting. I thought the window object is the browser window and not any particular div?

Comment: @AlxVallejo: Ah, CodeMirror! Now we’re getting somewhere! Are you using it on an `<iframe>`? Is that `<iframe>` huge, by any chance? (Hint: if it’s the CodeMirror `<iframe>` and there’s a lot of code in it, it probably is.)

Comment: @minitech - This is only in relation to the jfiddle example, not my own project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this was a result of a hidden div element on my page. I had a thickbox link that would pull this hidden content. Removing this fixed the jQuery.width()!

Surprising, not sure if helpful, but is the answer indeed.

Answer (score 10):

This can be just as simple as a missing or incorrect DOCTYPE (affected Chrome but not IE).

Interestingly this isn't even a jQuery issue - it affects `document.documentElement.clientHeight` too.

**Without doctype:**

[image]

**With doctype:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

[image]

I thought I had a layout template on my page, but it turned out I didn't - and therefore didn't have DOCTYPE.

Answer (score 5):

You're doing everything right, and you're not getting the values you should. This is not how jQuery is supposed to behave.

In this very page, I tested out the functions you were calling to see what their values would be. They did represent accurately the actual width and height of the visible page in my window. Here's the results.

### Chrome, with the standard Dev console

[image: Some calls to the window width and height in jQuery, returning correct results for pixels on screen]

### Firefox, with Firebug

[image: Some calls to the window width and height in jQuery, returning correct results for pixels on screen]

### Something is very wrong on your end

jQuery's `$(window).height()` is supposed to display the visible viewport. See the docs on [jQuery's height function](http://api.jquery.com/height/#height):

> This method is also able to find the height of the window and document.
>
> ```
> $(window).height(); // returns height of browser viewport
> $(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document
> ```

`window.height` is a settable value things can interfere with, but `$(window).height()` is unaffected by changes to it.

## What's going wrong exactly?

Whatever is going on, whatever function you're calling, you are not calling jQuery's implementation of `$(window).height()`.

Using your browser's developer console, put a break point on the line where you call `$(window).height()` and step into the function call. What is *actually* being called when you call `$(window).height()`? You need to find this out.

#### Has someone replaced the height function with a new or better one?

A strong suspicion of mine is that some part of the code base you're working with has gone and done this:

```
// Replace jQuery's height function with a better one to fix bug XYZ
$(window).height = function brandNewHeightFunction() {
    return someVeryWrongValue;
};
```

If so, when you step into the height function, it may in fact *not* enter into a part of the jQuery library, but another part of your own libraries. Find out what necessitated it and see what you can do about it. If you simply remove this functionality, other stuff depending on it working this way may start breaking.

#### Has someone gone and modified/customised your jQuery library?

Check to see if this has happened with whoever you can, and whatever history tools you have available. What version of jQuery are you using? Download the same one from the jQuery site if possible, and see the code you see when you step into the window height function is the same one as you see there.

Redownload jQuery and reference it. If your window height function suddenly starts working, someone may have done this. Find out why this was customised. If you repair it, other stuff depending on this behaviour might start breaking.

Comment: It looks like the replacement is trying to return the document size instead.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here, it looks that jquery (and dom in general) is not calculating sizes correctly in quirksmode.

Two solutions:

1. Add doctype html at the top of your page, or
2. Use window.innerHeight, window.innerWidth if first option is not an option.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is my experience that `$(document).height();` is typically what you want in most scenarios. The difference being if the page is bigger than the window (has scroll bars), you will get the full height of the entire scrollable document while `$(window).height()` will only get you the height of the currently sized tab.

So if you want an element to take up the full size of the window + any scrollable area below the fold `$(document).height` is the way to go.

There is definitely a use case for both though.

Answer (score -1):

jquery uses clientWidth and height that returns value of current showing page excluding scroll bar space there is one way to make it accurate do overflow:hidden to your body tag then you will get the original viewport size